# Can <link rel="preload" ...> be used on a specific one page?

Tags: image, optimization, carousel, preload, image-preloader

I have a BigCommerce store with customized code, on my home page I have an image carousel & for site speed purposes I would like to preload the carousel images. I added the code to preload all my images in the carousel, but when I pushed my code live I noticed that the images were being preloaded on all pages of my site, (which was causing warnings to popup on those pages) even though the code was on the home.html page specifically. Is there a way to avoid these warnings from popping up? Can I preload images for a specific page only?

Comment: "Can I preload images for a specific page only?" — Put the `<link>` tag only in that page. (How you persuade your CMS to do that depends on how your CMS works).

Comment: Have you achieved to do so?! I want to do the same and could you tell me what the whole line for <link rel="preload">